Maximum point of a function about binomial coefficients
For a fixed positive integer $m$, define $$g(d)=\sum_{j=d+1}^m\binom{m}{j}\binom{j-1}{d},\ \ 1\leq d\leq m-1.$$
I used MATLAB to calculate the value of $g$ and it seems that $g(d)$ is maximal iff $d=\left[\frac{m-1}{3}\right]$.
My try: Using the formula $$\sum_{k=q}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{q}=2^{n-q}\binom{n}{q},$$ the problem is equivalent to that $$\sum_{j=0}^{m-d}\frac{d}{m-j}\binom{m-d}{j}\leq 2^{m-d-1}\Leftrightarrow d\leq\left[\frac{m-1}{3}\right].$$

Edit: The problem is almost solved except for the case $m=3k+1$. In this case, the only thing left to do is proving $$g(3k+1,k)>g(3k+1,k-1)$$
(here we regard $g(d)$ as $g(m,d)$.
Actually, I can prove $g(d)$ is strictly increasing below $d=\left[\frac{m-1}{3}\right]$ for almost all cases. The proof is by induction. But this doesn't work when $m=3k+1$ and $d=k$ since there is a "gap" when $m$ increases from $3k$ to $3k+1$ due to the floor function.

This is probably not too helpful, but I can prove that $g(d)=\sum_{n=d}^{m-1}2^{n-d}\binom md$.

@MikeEarnest The summation is irrelavent to m and d! So $g(d)=(2^{m-d}-1)\binom{m}{d}$ and the solution follows easily from computing $\frac{g(d)}{g(d-1)}$.

@MikeEarnest You can write an answer below to explain your computation if you like and I will accept it!

I am very sorry, but I made a big typo. The actual formula is $g(d)=\sum_{n=d}^{m-1}2^{n-d}\binom{\color{red}n}{d}$. So you cannot pull anything out.

@MikeEarnest Alright. But how did you get this ? Which formula you used?

Problem solved. First of all, you need to calculate $g(m,d)+g(m,d-1)$ and $g(m,d)+g(m-1,d-1)$. The second one need to use summation by part formula.
The induction on $m$ solves most cases.
The case $g(3k+1,k)>g(3k+1,k-1)$ can be proved by using the representation $\sum_{j=0}^{m-d}\frac{d}{m-j}\binom{m-d}{j}$ which comes from $\frac{g(d-1)}{2^{m-d-1}\binom{m}{d}}$. Now transform this representation into integral and use Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

Here is a different representation for your sum, which may or may not be helpful.
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=d+1}^m \binom mj\binom{j-1}d
  &=\sum_{j=d+1}^m \sum_{\ell=0}^{m-1}\binom{\ell}{j-1}\binom{j-1}d
\\&=\sum_{\ell=0}^{m-1}\sum_{j=d+1}^m \binom{\ell}{j-1}\binom{j-1}d
\\&=\sum_{\ell=0}^{m-1}\binom{\ell}d2^{\ell-d}.
\end{align}
In the first step, we use the hockey stick identity to expand $\binom mj$ into $\sum_{\ell=0}^{m-1}\binom{\ell}{j-1}$.
In the final step, we use the result that $\sum_{k=d}^{\ell} \binom{\ell}k\binom kd=2^{\ell-d}\binom{\ell}d$.
